# Local Install of Existing Wordpress Site with XAMPP Redirects to Install Page

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I've followed several guides on how to migrate my existing Wordpress website onto my local computer, running it offline with XAMPP.
Everything appears to be installed, all my own files from wp-content, the database, all things configured to point at [http://localhost/wordpress/], however when I go to any address such as "[http://localhost/wordpress]" it redirects me to "[http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php]". On a previous attempt, before reinstalling and trying again, I followed the install process, and it was a fresh website, without any of my content.

I've seen this problem appear before (read a comment), however the solution didn't apply to me (improper address in wp-config.php. I've followed all the instructions to the letter, but I'm getting this redirect suggesting something hasn't gone right. I suppose the fix is small, however I can't figure out what to do. Can anyone possibly provide some help?

Comment: If you followed the install process and got a fresh website, it sounds like your database config in `wp-config.php` is ok (it can connect to, and find, the database named there), but it's not seeing the tables.  After it does the fresh install, is there a second set of tables in the database?  Maybe the `$table_prefix` variable in your `wp-config.php` is different?

Comment: @Hobo - Yeah good spot, but I'd already seen that and changed the default "wp_" to "wordpress_" to match my database.

Comment: @Hobo - oops didn't realise "return" submits the comment. In my database I'd changed all of the existing links for my website to point at [http://localhost/wordpress/]. I only have one wordpress database that I can see.

Comment: I wonder if it's anything to do with the .htaccess file or index.php. At the moment they're both the default, and exist together in htdocs. I have another index.php file in my htdocs/wordpress folder.

Comment: I think it's more likely to be something to do with your database than .htaccess or index.php, but I could be wrong.  I'd start by comparing your database structure after your import (table definitions, not content at this stage) with the structure created if you run the install process on the empty database.  Failing that, does [turning on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) show anything useful?

Comment: So I set up my wp-config.php to debug, however after several access attempts to the website, a debug.log file has yet to materialise. 

What do you mean, "the structure created if you run the install process on the empty database" - just reuploading the database..?

I'm looking at the charsets now. My server charset is "UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)".. all match.. Hmm..

Comment: Sorry, I went to bed after my last comment.  I meant drop all the tables in the database, and run the WordPress install.  See what tables are created, and see if they're the same as the ones you're importing.  If they are, I'm confused.  If they're not, we might be closer to finding a solution.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you replying.

So, I've been following this guide step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7z4uzfcyNQ

I've completely reinstalled XAMPP. Then I extracted the latest copy of Wordpress into the htdocs directory. Interesting dissimilarity, I didn't get a wordpress database installed on myphp, unlike in the video guide.

And now I'm trying to upload my database, however I'm now getting an error of "#1046 - No database selected". Even on the previous database versions which I'd managed to upload previously!

Comment: Oh wait, I panicked too soon. I'd not created the database to import into. Just did it and the site is working!
Pro tip: follow the instructions and don't mess around with any of the files unless the guide tells you to.

So now I can see my website, it isn't redirecting me to the install page. The whole website is hugely broken, but I'll work on that ;)

Thanks, @Hobo ! :)

Comment: A final note. Changing the default "$table_prefix  = 'wp_';" to 'wordpress_' made it go to the install page, just now.

Comment: Great news - glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to go into phpMyAdmin and update the siteurl entry in the wp_options table. It should probably be something like `http://localhost/yousite/` Have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with local WordPress development 5 years on, you could try using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) instead of XAMPP.

I made a repository that will get you up and running quickly with it, it takes a pre-existing WordPress site and allows you to run it on localhost - https://github.com/lumonald/existing-wordpress-development-docker/